# Is it possible to change from .NET Framework 4.8 to 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, .net

Is it possible to change from .NET Framework 4.8 to 4.7.2? In my "Turn Windows features on or off", I have ASP.NET 4.8 listed. I wish to change this to 4.7.2 I tried downloading and installing the developer pack from here (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472), but no luck on changing it inside "Windows features on or off".

[image]

Comment: if you have 4.8 then you have 4.7.2 automatically. did you install developer pack or runtime?

Comment: I am curious, What exactly are you trying to do? Are you looking to **target** .NET 4.7.2 with your application?

Comment: Windows on or off features don't really matter in what your settings are in Visual Studio. If you want certain .net framework for your project, then make sure that .net version is installed. I suppose you could turn windows features on to get a particular .net framework installed. Little need to turn off any particalr version of .net (really don't matter how many you have installed). All you care is that .net frame work is installed. So don't bother with turning windows features off. Don't matter if you have every version from 2.0 to the latest installed. No need to remove or turn off existing

Comment: However, this is a fine question, since often I have to deploy software to some server - they can't change their .net for me, so yes, I often have to match what they have - often pull down a few versions that they not yet installed. If that server or target computer does not have the correct version - yes you BETTER match with the highest version on that server. do NOT as suggested assume that because you have some higher version you are ok - its what on the target computer that matters. I am more confused by those wondering why this question is being asked! Common issue we deal with

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal in this case the question is about running on a *higher* version, which isn't a problem. That's why people are asking "why?". It shouldn't matter. There's almost certainly a *different* problem that the OP assumed would be solved by downgrading

Comment: @Bill why are you trying to downgrade? Running on 4.8 isn't a problem. Did you have an actual problem you want to solve and assumed you need to downgrade to fix it? It won't. You can solve the *actual* problem though, whatever it is

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real particular issue by going back on the projects .net version.

The only requirement is that you have the correct version of .net installed on your computer. I suppose you "can" go into windows settings - and if the .net framework is not selected, then fine.

I would NOT suggest that you bother to disable say some given .net framework in the windows settings.

if you need a particular .net framework - then make sure it is installed on your development computer. once done, then in project settings you can select the framework - say like this:

[image]

So no, don't disable any .net framework. Sure, you can enable as such, but I would not mess or bother to remove existing frameworks.

About the ONLY real issues are:

If any library or referenced assemblies are LATER then the framework you select, then you can't use such tools, and external libraries.

And of course the target computer then has to have AT LEAST that level of .net installed.

In fact, in some cases, especially some web hosting providers - they are often VERY MUCH behind on what versions of .net are avaible.

And then of course often your have a 4-5 year old production server. They often don't allow updates to such servers to later versions of .net, so you are in your case - can you roll back, or choose a lower .net framework.

I certainly suggest that you adjust, pick, and get your development cycle working on the lowest min target framework. That way you not only avoid (even by accident) using some libraries and tools that can't run on that target web server.

Another FYI? If you select/change that framework in the VS project settings (as per above screen shot), I suggest that after doing so, you exit VS, and re-enter. I experienced some issues when not doing this exit of VS when downgrading the project.

You then want to do a clean project, and then do a re-build all. If that re-build all don't spit out any errors, then you are in rather good shape and should be ok.

Comment: The question asks how to downgrade a 4.8 runtime to 4.7, not deploy to a server with an old runtime. And, as the screenshot shows, the `the lowest min target framework.` on that server is 4.8. That's the runtime installed on all *supported* Windows 10 and Windows 2019 servers

Comment: Downgrading the .net project and ramifications are front and center to this debate. (VS project settings MUST be a issue else there is no issue! - you  just change the VS project and all problems go away).. A POSSBILE considering here is to thus modify the VS project settings and not change the target machine. Again, might not be a option, but then again it MIGHT be and is worthy of considering in this discussion. Agreed no reason to downgrade exists that I can think of here 4.8 will run 4.7. So yes, 100% agree it makes no sense to downgrade the server.

Answer (score -3):

Open the Project in Visual Studio >>> Go to Project Tab on Top >>> Select Project Properties >>> Change the Target Framework[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rEPx.jpg) from the Dropdown >>> Click Yes to Save the Same